# How run javascript script immediately after dom tree is loaded to avoid the user from seeing the "single buffering" effect?

Tags: javascript, dom

Premise: I need to apply changes trough JavaScript because the free platform on which my site is based does not allow changes to some parts of the template, so I can't insert the scripts in the source through the  tag, but I can insert them in the script administration panel provided by the platform.

The script put in the panel are normally called up before the building of the DOM tree, so I have to insert the scripts in the $(function) to force the call at the end of the dom tree building, but in this way the function is called after the page has been drawn and the user first sees the old page and then the new page generating a "single buffering" effect.

Summarize:

1 - browser loading page and display it

2 - browser loading image and display it

3 - browser execute script and display changes

Quite often the point two take about 1 seconds or more so the old page is displayed for that time.

Can I force javascript to run code between point one and point two, so that point three become point two, and point two become point three?

I try:

`$(function) {}`

`$(window).onload() {}`

`$(document).ready() {}`

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {});`

Nothing of these works as I want.

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

```
// add 'timer' function which will be called once every millisecond
var step = setInterval(step, 1);

function step() {
  // verify if element is loaded
  if (document.getElementById('*element-id*')) {

    // add code here

    // stop function call
    window.clearInterval(step);
  }
}
```

This work very well for me.